# Dictionary data ito d3 line chart - Django Python in server side

Tags: javascript, python, django, dictionary, d3.js

I have a dictionary object of date time and value. I have set up my axis accordingly in the following formats;

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format(""d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height,0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
```

What I can't get ym head aroud is how to write an equivalent of this;

```
        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (data) { return x(data.property1); })
        .y(function (data) { return y(data.property2); });
```

But using the dictionary from my django view. Should I return a render_to_response with my data dictionary and put my faith in the hope that data.property1 will set my x values to what I generated in my view. Or should I have some sort of ajax call in the above functions to return the data via HttpResponse(data).

I'm a javascript and d3 noob but don't have enough time to learn either in enough detail, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**You are right that you should use `HttpResponse()`.**

D3.js has a nifty [`d3.json`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) method that will perform a GET request at the URL "/myDataURL/" and parse the response as a JSON object:

```
d3.json("/myDataURL/", function(error, data) {
    // ... (Use `data` to load the visualization.)
});
```

Which means you can easily send your `dict` in a JSON format from Django:

```
import json
def myView(request):
    // ... Prepare the `data` dict.
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

*Note: using HttpResponse with content_type can be simplified in recent Django 1.7+ by using [`JsonResponse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)*

---

**Now putting it all together**, if you want to actually load the data as lines in (for example) a line chart, you could use ([source](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)):

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

d3.json("/myDataURL/", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  // ... Set up the axes. See the source above for detailed instructions.

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, how would I set the x and y tags then? i can see how I would use the json response with an existing post method I have but I still can't understand how I would access and use that data

Comment: What type of D3 visual are you using (chart/network/etc.)? The specific keywords vary slightly (but the idea is the same).

Comment: That's what I figured. :P Does my update make sense?

Comment: looks good (i really appreciate this btw) the URL what does this call? also how would i handle this (if the URL points to the view) as a GET?

Comment: @Mark, Updated again. Gist: The "sample" URL I used above is "/myDataURL/". Also, d3.json  performs a GET request by default. Simply passing it a valid* URL is enough. (*ie: the URL is properly placed in your Django urls.py file)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try and implement and let you know how I get on

Comment: do you know of a way to check if a get request is json is python?

Comment: Er, Why?... Python's `json.dumps()` will *always* return a valid JSON string if given a dictionary/list.

Comment: as i said i'm a noob with this, what i was wanting to do was to do something like if request.is_json() then return the date and close parameters to the json function. i already have a get request in the same view which returns options for a drop downso need to distinguish

Comment: Quick note: the Django `request` is not JSON-formatted. The *contents* of the `request` can; think of the request as the *vehicle* for information. while that may seem like an easy solution. Also, I would recommend you **break up different functionality into different functions**; having a single view that does something in one case and does something completely differently in another case ***will*** get confusing. :)